# MongoDB query not equal

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'am trying to make some mongoDB query, but it doesn't work.
This is how object look:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c616e96aeddc93e2c076101"),
    "_class" : "school.domain.mongo.User",
    "username" : "test1234",
    "password" : "test1234",
    "status" : "ACTIVE",
    "time_created" : ISODate("2019-02-11T13:46:14.753+01:00"),
    "last_modified" : ISODate("2019-02-11T13:46:14.753+01:00")
}
```

Now i need to find user who are modified their data in the last 24 hours
This is query that i try but it doesn't work

```
db.getCollection('user').find({
    $and : [
        {"status" : "ACTIVE"},
        {"last_modified" : { $lt: new Date(), $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))}},
        {"last_modified" : { $ne: "time_created"}}
    ]
})
```

User must be active, last modified in range now and 24 hours in past
And last modified must be different from time created, because if it's same than user is only created and not modified in the past 24 hours.
I've tried this query and it still give me users that have same last_modified and time_created values.

Comment: Why unaccept the answer?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet accidentally. Could you pls look this second question if you know what could be problem

Comment: Sorry but I don't have idea about spring boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to match the two fields from the same document

```
db.getCollection('user').find({
  "status" : "ACTIVE",
  "last_modified": { "$lt": new Date(), "$gte": new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1)) }
  "$expr": { "$ne": ["$last_modified", "$time_created"] }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This query from @Anthony Winzlet working i Robo3T. But when i use it in spring to make custom query:

```
@Query("{ $and : [ {'status' : 'ACTIVE'}, {'last_modified' : { $lt: new Date(), $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))}}, {'$expr': { '$ne': ['$last_modified', '$time_created']}}]}")
    public List<User> findModifiedUsers();
```

doesn't work, it return me some error on starting project.
So i tried to make query with Criteria in spring:

```
Query query = new Query();
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();  
            criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("status").is(UserStatus.ACTIVE), Criteria.where("last_modified").lt(new Date()).gt(lastDay), Criteria.where("time_created").ne("last_modified"));
```

but it doesn't work, it returns me all users like there is no this last criteria not equal last_modified and time_created.